# lag issues javascript over time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, lag

I have a technical question to ask you. I'm currently developing a huge application in javascript with timer and request and I have a strange question.

When I'm working for two hours on my project (so refreshing page, commit, re-refresh, ...), I have no problems but when I'm working one more hour, my application begin to have some lags issues, opening the console can become a nightmare. Is that a server issues or a computer issues ??

I'm using a lot of timer (setTimeout and setInterval)

Can we dynamically release all memory from chrome / firefox / safari / ...

If you have any idea, please, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

a alternate way of using timer is:

1. just one timer (setInterval) call every minimum duration of timers;
2. all other timer are triggered by this timer, on specified times that main timer calls;

you can find some clues in jQuery about [animation & effects](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js).

I think this concept is probably from task scheduling and [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) on computer science.